# Setting absolute label size ArcMap10

Tags: arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.1

I have an architecture plan with elevation measurements. When I display the labels (Bullet Leader style), the automatic scaling moves the label on top of the background layers, obstructing them.

I have tried defining the Feature Weight in Placement Properties as `High` in the architectural features, but that creates new problems with the zoom level at which labels are shown.

So my question is, is there a way to make labels behave in such a way so that their absolute size is constant (shrink and grow when I change the zoom) yet the placement properties are automatic?

I thought about using plain text labels and manually placing them in the correct position, but I have hundreds of elevation points, and I want to keep the plan neat (for publication) without different length.

Just to clear things, I have one points feature class of elevation points, and many polygon and line feature classes of the architecture.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this kind of task not better suited to CAD software?

Comment: It may not be the solution but have you tried setting a [Reference Scale](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00660000043v000000)?

Comment: I know this calls for a CAD, but I was wondering if using ArcMap is possible.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have tried the Reference Scale, but I'm using 1:25 and 1:50 scales, this tool is not fine tuned enough, as I would describe it, to handle it.

Comment: I found a half baked solution. I made the layout page size larger, which enabled me to shrink the relative text size to fit inside polygons. 

But the problem still stands. playing with Placement properties Initial point placement seems to affect the arrow in the label rather than the label text itself.